# How to create a login module with two user levels in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, authentication

I would like to make a login page with 2 different user levels, Doctor & Parent. How can I do it in Yii....

**Two tables listed below....For both users email address is the username.**

CREATE TABLE `Doctor` (
  `doctor_email` VARCHAR(50),
  `password` VARCHAR(50),
  `doctor_name` VARCHAR(50),
  `doctor_phone` INT(10),
  `speciality` VARCHAR(200),
  PRIMARY KEY  (`doctor_email`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Parent` (
  `parent_email` VARCHAR(50),
  `parent_name` VARCHAR(50),
  `password` VARCHAR(20),
  `parent_address` VARCHAR(100),
  `parent_phone` INT(10),
  PRIMARY KEY  (`parent_email`)
);

This is the authenticate() function in UserIdentity.php

public function authenticate() {

```
    $record1 = Doctor::model()->findByAttributes(array('doctor_email' => $this->username));
    $record2 = Parents::model()->findByAttributes(array('parent_email' => $this->username));

    if ($record1 !== NULL) {
        if ($record1->password == $this->password) {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;

        } else {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        }
    } else if ($record2 !== NULL) {
        if ($record2->password == $this->password) {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;

        } else {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        }
    }
    return !$this->errorCode;
}
```

This is my login() function in models/LoginForm.php

public function login() {

```
    if ($this->_identity === null) {
        $this->_identity = new UserIdentity($this->username, $this->password);

        $this->_identity->authenticate();
        if ($this->_identity->record1 !== NULL)
            $this->isDoc = TRUE;
        else if ($this->_identity->record2 !== NULL)
            $this->isDoc = FALSE;
    }
    if ($this->_identity->errorCode === UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE) {
        $duration = $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0; // 30 days
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity, $duration);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

And this is the actionLogin() in siteContoller.php

public function actionLogin() {
        $model = new LoginForm;

```
    // if it is ajax validation request
    if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'login-form') {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if (isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];


        if ($model->validate() && $model->login()) {


            if ($model->isDoc) {
                $this->redirect(array('/doctor/index'));

            } elseif ($model->isDoc == FALSE) {
                $this->redirect(array('/parents/index'));

            }
        }
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login', array('model' => $model));
}
```

When login for both users its redirect to '/parents/index'. Can anyone tell me what am I do wrong? or any idea.....Thanx in advance..

Answer (score 1):

As I can see the problem is that `$model->isDoc` is Null. And as you have used `$model->isDoc == FALSE`

I Mean the double equal operator. so this condition is getting true.

Try with `$model->isDoc === FALSE` (triple equal operator)

I am pretty sure that it will take you to the login form again.

If I am not wrong above then the real problem persists here

```
if ($this->_identity->record1 !== NULL)
            $this->isDoc = TRUE;
        else if ($this->_identity->record2 !== NULL)
            $this->isDoc = FALSE;
```

Try to `var_dump($this->_identity->record1)` as well as `var_dump($this->_identity->record2)` and check whether any of them is not getting null in any case

Or you can try this

in your UserIdentity class you need to declare two variable s as

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
public $record1;
public $record2;

}
```

Now in your **authenticate()**

change `$record1` to `$this->record1` and `$record2` to `$this->record2`